# Android starts empty activity

Tags: android, debugging, android-activity

I am starting an acitivity the usual way like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), GalleryActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(PUTEXTRA_IDENTIFIER_MACHINE, selectedMachine);
                startActivity(intent);
```

**Problem:** I can stop everywhere I like in my app for debugging. But it is not possible to stop in the GalleryActivity. Even not in the `onCreate()` method before any mistake could be made by me.

So everything I see is always a pure white page coming up.

How can I make stopping for debug in that activity possible?

It seems like android is not starting the stuff I have implemented but some kind of dummy acitivity. So when I log something in the new activity, for example, nothing happens. Where can that come from ?

registration of that activtiy in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.mego.smscloud.reviewmaschine.gallery.GalleryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:parentActivityName="com.mego.smscloud.reviewmaschine.ReviewMaschineActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.mego.smscloud.reviewmaschine.ReviewMaschineActivity" />
        </activity>
```

activity

```
public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{

   (...)

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_view);
        setTitle(null);

      (...) some init 

    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState, PersistableBundle outPersistentState) {
        settingsMenu.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState, outPersistentState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        CharSequence title = new SpannableBuilder(this)
                .createStyle().setFont(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD).apply()
                .append(photoList.get(position).getName()).append("\n")
                .clearStyle()
                .append(photoList.get(position).getDate())
                .build();
        titleView.setText(title);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

    }
}
```

**Note:** I have already added

```
minifyEnabled false
```

to my gradle file.

What it does look like (I have textviews placed inside the layout):

[image]

The logs I get:

```
07-05 06:42:04.216 25558-25583/com.mego.smscloud W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-05 06:42:04.216 25558-25583/com.mego.smscloud W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe3097920, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-05 06:42:05.645 25558-25558/com.mego.smscloud I/Choreographer: Skipped 82 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-05 06:42:07.324 25558-25583/com.mego.smscloud W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
07-05 06:42:07.324 25558-25583/com.mego.smscloud W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xe456a580, error=EGL_SUCCESS
07-05 06:42:12.247 25558-25558/com.mego.smscloud I/Choreographer: Skipped 292 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Comment: do you have any log information? are you shure about the path to activity in AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @Silwester: I have updated my post. I have even tried it with a completely clean activity only with setContentView and I still get that behavior.

Comment: ok, I suggested solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal onCreate method should look like

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   // do stuff
}
```

I think that can be the problem. [Docs here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#onCreate(android.os.Bundle))